Flutter with Firebase Messaging not open on background message
I'm building a system that after the user made his sign up, he'll receive a push notification if the account was approved or not. I'm working in the rejection scenario, the user should receive a notification on background and when clicked the app should grab the route from data, actually from RemoteMessage.data, this is comming from the cloud function, I already printed it, it's working properly) and redirect the user. But nothing is currently happening with the app, this is my implementation:
My main file:
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();
  notificationService.initialize();
  notificationService.handleBackgroundNotification(message);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
  );
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    NotificationService().initialize();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserLoginService()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserSignUpService()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PageService()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: "Account creation module",
        theme: lightMode,
        darkTheme: darkMode,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        navigatorKey: AppNavigator.instance.navigatorKey,
        routes: AppRoutes.getRoutes(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And my notification service:
class NotificationService {

  void initialize() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      handleForegroundNotification(message);
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      handleBackgroundNotification(message);
    });
  }

  void handleBackgroundNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.data["route"] != null) {
      AppNavigator.instance.navigateTo(message.data["route"], arguments: message.data);
    }
  }

  void handleForegroundNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
    BuildContext context = AppNavigator.instance.context;
    RemoteNotification notification = message.notification!;
    Flushbar(
      title: notification.title,
      message: notification.body,
      flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
      flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.GROUNDED,
      isDismissible: true,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.info_outline,
        size: 28.0,
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
      ),
      leftBarIndicatorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
    ).show(context);
  }
}

The AppNavigator does only redirects, but this is the implementation too:
class AppNavigator {
  static final AppNavigator _instance = AppNavigator._();

  AppNavigator._();

  static AppNavigator get instance => _instance;

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  BuildContext get context => navigatorKey.currentContext!;

  void pop() => navigatorKey.currentState?.pop();
  Future<dynamic>? navigateTo(String routeName, {Object? arguments}) => navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(routeName, arguments: arguments);
  Future<dynamic>? navigateToReplacing(String routeName, {Object? arguments}) => navigatorKey.currentState?.pushReplacementNamed(routeName, arguments: arguments);
}

Even with all the things apparently set up, when I click in the notification my app opens in a empty screen, what am I missing here?
PS: The foreground and when the app is running in the background works, just when the app was terminated that make it crash the scenario I told.
